# F#: operator precedence

Tags: f#, operator-precedence

This code doesn't compile:

```
let f (x:byte) = printfn "%d" x

let b = int 'a'
f(byte <| b ||| 0x1)
```

```
(4,17): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    byte
but here has type
    int
```

- http://ideone.com/C6KoCQ

The F# operator table states the *backward pipe* operaotor `(<|)` which has a form of `(< op)` has a lower precedence than the *bitwise or* operator `(|||)`:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx

So I thought `(byte <| b ||| 0x1)` should be parsed as `(byte <| (b ||| 0x1))`.  But the compiler error message suggests it is parsed as `((byte <| b) ||| 0x1)`.  What's happening here?

Comment: yes I think you are right and the precedence table is wrong/misleading in this case - I would suggest to just switch to `|>` as in `b ||| 0x1 |> byte`

Comment: I just had a look at the FSharp specs (http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.1/FSharpSpec-3.1-working.docx) and there `<|` indeed has higher precedence than `|||` (if I read the table right) - so most likely it's either an error in the MSDN docs or it was changed and not updated

Comment: @CarstenKönig Interesting... If you posted it as an "answer," I would have accepted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a look at the FSharp specs and there `<|` indeed has higher precedence than `|||` (if I read the table right)

So most likely it's either an error in the MSDN docs or it was changed and not updated.

It's on page 35:

[image]

Comment: I think "`|OP`" covers the *bitwise or* operator `(|||)`

Comment: there is a text above that says that `OP` matches only if it is not defined anywhere else and I assumed that it might match with the or  (maybe was wrong there) - just have a look yourself

Comment: anyway it might be top-bottom, left-right so even if it matches the same line <| would still come before ||| - so I think it's not really a bug (but I find the precedence rules strange anyway - wish you could define it yourself like Haskell instead of using some strange prefix-symbol-rules)

Comment: for example `(fun x -> x*2) <| 2 |> (fun x -> x+1)` is `5` so `<|` has higher precedence than `|>` and this would match the left-to-right assumption ;)